# Differences between MSMQ and Other IPC Methods

Tags: ipc, msmq

I am reading tutorials about msmq to understand what it is used for.

I know it is a type of interprocess communication method. But Microsoft didn't add msmq under this topic:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

So is there a special reason for that? What are the differences between MSMQ and other IPC methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

MSMQ is a bit heavyweight for interprocess communication on the same box. It's usually used for reliable communication between boxes, or on the same box when offline queuing is needed.

For IPC on the same box use the WCF NetNamedPipeBinding.

Answer (score 1):

MSMQ is a messaging platform that is used to connect systems that require some or all of secure transfer, ordered messaging, transactional messaging, offline support.

MSMQ can be used for IPC as well, but the performance will no way near IPC.

MSQM isolates applications by using a queue, which can either be a local queue or a queue on another computer, while IPC is more or less direct communication between applications.

MSMQ is often used in combination with BizTalk where you can achieve completely asynchronous and reliable routing of messages between systems.

So MSMQ is more for Enterprise level communication.